# web.xmlでフィルタ設定を行うと、起動中の例外が発生する(フィルタで指定したクラスの動作をデバックで確認すると正常動作している)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

web.xmlでフィルタ設定を行うと、起動中の例外が発生します。
(フィルタで指定したクラスの動作をデバックで確認すると正常動作している。jsp表示時にcssの読み込みが出来なくなってしまう)

web.xmlの設定状況↓

```html
 ---web.xml---
   <filter>
    <filter-name>abcFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filterclass</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>abcFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

コンソール出力↓

```html
---コンソール---
～前半省略～
情報: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read [金 9 04 17:30:56 JST 2015]
情報: Initialization processed in 549 ms [金 9 04 17:30:56 JST 2015]
情報: サービス Catalina を起動します [金 9 04 17:30:56 JST 2015]
情報: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24 [金 9 04 17:30:56 JST 2015]
情報: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. [金 9 04 17:30:56 JST 2015]
重大: フィルタfilterClass の起動中の例外です [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
重大: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
重大: 以前のエラーのためにコンテキストの起動が失敗しました [] [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
警告: Name = postgres Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "30" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored. [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
警告: Name = postgres Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "108000000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored. [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
情報: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
情報: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
情報: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
情報: Server startup in 1436 ms [金 9 04 17:30:57 JST 2015]
```

解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filterclassを含むプロジェクトの配置がなされていません。
filterclassを含むプロジェクトをTomcatのlib内にエクスポートします。
そうすると、エラーが解消されます。